# best way of replacing all tags in a string with java

Tags: java, string, replace, stringbuilder

I have a service method that takes a String and then replaces tags in the String with items from a tag library.  As follows:

```
for( MetaDataDTO tag : tagValues )
{
    message = message.replace( tag.getKey(), tag.getText1() );
}
```

Obviously; this make heaps of new strings and is BAD.  But the StringBuilder replace method is cumbersome to use for multiple strings inside one string.  How can I make my method more efficient?

It is for use with blocks of text such as:

Dear #firstName#, your application for #applicationType# has been #approvedRejected# sorry.

Where #firstName#, etc are the keys in a meta data database.  It is also possible that tags may not be surrounded by hash characters.

Comment: How many strings are you going to create ? Is it really a major headache ? i.e. how many of the above search/replaces will you be performing ?

Comment: this is part of a meta data package for putting things on my web pages. so can be called heaps of times with potentially 20 to 40 replacements on each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys.  Certainly learned more about java.  Here is my solution.  It is this way to support different looking tags and tags within tags:

```
private static String replaceAllTags(String message, Map< String, String > tags)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( message );
    boolean tagFound = false;
    /**
     * prevent endless circular text replacement loops
     */
    long recurrancyChecker = 5000;

    do
    {
        tagFound = false;
        Iterator it = tags.entrySet().iterator();
        while( it.hasNext() )
        {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();

            int start = sb.indexOf( pairs.getKey().toString() );

            while( start > -1 && --recurrancyChecker > 0 )
            {
                int length = pairs.getKey().toString().length();
                sb.replace( start, start + length, pairs.getValue().toString() );
                start = sb.indexOf( pairs.getKey().toString() );
                tagFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while( tagFound && --recurrancyChecker > 0 );
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Basically you want to copy the execution of [Matcher.replaceAll()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) like so:

```
public static String replaceTags(String message, Map<String, String> tags) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+)#");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
  boolean result = m.find();
  if (result) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    do {
      m.appendReplacement(sb, tags.containsKey(m.group(1) ? tags.get(m.group(1)) : "");
      result = m.find();
    } while (result);
    m.appendTail(sb);
    message = sb.toString();
  }
  return message;
}
```

**Note:** I've made an assumption about the valid tag (namely \w in the regex). You will need to cater this for what's really valid (eg "#([\w_]+)#").

I've also assumed the tags above looks something like:

```
Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<String, String>();
tags.add("firstName", "Skippy");
```

and not:

```
tags.add("#firstName#", "Skippy");
```

If the second is correct you'll need to adjust accordingly.

This method makes exactly one pass across the message string so it doesn't get much more efficient than this.

Comment: should that be m.appendReplacement?

Comment: One simple efficiency improvement you could make is to compile the regular expression outside of the method call: 

 private static Pattern _tagPattern = Pattern.compile(...);

 public static String replaceTags(...) {
    Matcher m = _tagPattern.matcher(message);
 }

Comment: @Henry: I used to do things like that but my testing on modern JVMs indicates the cost of creating the pattern to be close to nothing. Also, if you do that you then introduce concurrency/locking issues. A much simpler and less error-prone design is worth the slightly higher cost.

Comment: @cletus just regarding the concurrency concern, the javadoc for the Pattern class says "instances of this class are immutable and are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads".

Answer (score 2):

Solution from library: 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:{version}'.

Usage example:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
        valuesMap.put("name", "World!");
        String expectedResult = "Hello, World!";

        // default - prefix: "${", suffix: "}"
        String source1 = "Hello, ${name}";
        StringSubstitutor sub1 = new StringSubstitutor(valuesMap);
        String result1 = sub1.replace(source1);
        System.out.println(expectedResult.equals(result1));

        // custom - prefix: "{{", suffix: "}}"
        String source2 = "Hello, {{name}}";
        StringSubstitutor sub2 = new StringSubstitutor(valuesMap, "{{", "}}");
        String result2 = sub2.replace(source2);
        System.out.println(expectedResult.equals(result2));
    }
}
```